# How change rows value in a "Map loop" in R-studio?

Tags: r, loops, dictionary, row

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(2, 5, 90, 77, 56, 65, 85, 75, 12, 24, 52, 
32), b = c(45, 78, 98, 55, 63, 12, 23, 38, 75, 68, 99, 73), c = c(77, 
85, 3, 22, 4, 69, 86, 39, 78, 36, 96, 11), d = c(52, 68, 4, 25, 
79, 120, 97, 20, 7, 19, 37, 67), e = c(14, 73, 91, 87, 94, 38, 
1, 685, 47, 102, 666, 74)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

and the script:

```
R <- Map(`+`, list(1:3), 0:3)
df_cum <- as.matrix(rep(NA, ncol(df)))
for (r in seq(R)) {
  for (f in seq(ncol(df))) {
    df_cum <- sapply(df[R[[r]],], function(x) (cumprod(1 + x) - 1)*100)
  }
}
```

I want to change all the first row values to "0", for each loop (1:3, 2:4, 3:5,...), before

```
df_cum <- sapply(df[R[[r]],], function(x) (cumprod(1 + x) - 1)*100)
```

I.e. for the first cicle 1:3 (df rows), the first row values change from "2, 45, 77, 52, 14" to "0, 0, 0, 0, 0".

How can I do?
Thx

Comment: try ` tmp <- df;
    tmp[1, ] <- 0` before the `sapply`

Comment: Why mix `for-loops` and `*apply+`? Describe what you are trying to do  and give the output you expect and probably someone will give you a better code to do the same.

Comment: Note that you are doing a double for loop and overwriting everything ance you get to the end of the inner loop

Comment: With df_cum I want generate a cumulative return, but i need that each first row contain values 0

Comment: @akrun in that way only the first row of df has values = 0. I don't need that. I need that the first row of each loop has values = 0